# Creating pyspark dataframe from parquet file exported from DMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-dms, apache-hudi

We are trying to read data from mysql database in RDS using DMS. The DMS outputs the data in parquet file format into s3 bucket.
From there it is read into a dataframe to create hudi dataset to check the deltas in the data using pyspark:

## code

```
%%configure -f
{
    "conf":  { 
             "spark.jars":"hdfs:///user/hadoop/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.31.jar, hdfs:///user/hadoop/hudi-spark-bundle.jar,hdfs:///user/hadoop/spark-avro.jar",
             "spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet":"false",     
             "spark.serializer":"org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer",
             "spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout": 3600,
             "spark.executor.memory": "5G",
             "spark.executor.cores": 3,
             "spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors":5
           } 
}

config = {
    "table_name": "ticket_table",
    "target": "s3://dms-rds-s3/hudi/hudi_test",
    "primary_key": "storeid",
    "sort_key": "ticket_updated_date",
    "commits_to_retain": "4"
}

# General Constants
HUDI_FORMAT = "org.apache.hudi"
TABLE_NAME = "hoodie.table.name"
RECORDKEY_FIELD_OPT_KEY = "hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field"
PRECOMBINE_FIELD_OPT_KEY = "hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field"
OPERATION_OPT_KEY = "hoodie.datasource.write.operation"
BULK_INSERT_OPERATION_OPT_VAL = "bulk_insert"
UPSERT_OPERATION_OPT_VAL = "upsert"
DELETE_OPERATION_OPT_VAL = "delete"
BULK_INSERT_PARALLELISM = "hoodie.bulkinsert.shuffle.parallelism"
UPSERT_PARALLELISM = "hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism"
S3_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = "hoodie.consistency.check.enabled"
HUDI_CLEANER_POLICY = "hoodie.cleaner.policy"
KEEP_LATEST_COMMITS = "KEEP_LATEST_COMMITS"
KEEP_LATEST_FILE_VERSIONS = "KEEP_LATEST_FILE_VERSIONS"
HUDI_COMMITS_RETAINED = "hoodie.cleaner.commits.retained"
HUDI_FILES_RETAINED = "hoodie.cleaner.fileversions.retained"
PAYLOAD_CLASS_OPT_KEY = "hoodie.datasource.write.payload.class.key()"
EMPTY_PAYLOAD_CLASS_OPT_VAL = "org.apache.hudi.EmptyHoodieRecordPayload"

# Hive Constants
HIVE_SYNC_ENABLED_OPT_KEY="hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable"
HIVE_PARTITION_FIELDS_OPT_KEY="hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields"
HIVE_ASSUME_DATE_PARTITION_OPT_KEY="hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.assume_date_partitioning"
HIVE_PARTITION_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_OPT_KEY="hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_extractor_class"
HIVE_TABLE_OPT_KEY="hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table"

# Partition Constants
NONPARTITION_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_OPT_VAL="org.apache.hudi.hive.NonPartitionedExtractor"
MULTIPART_KEYS_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_OPT_VAL="org.apache.hudi.hive.MultiPartKeysValueExtractor"
KEYGENERATOR_CLASS_OPT_KEY="hoodie.datasource.write.keygenerator.class"
NONPARTITIONED_KEYGENERATOR_CLASS_OPT_VAL="org.apache.hudi.keygen.NonpartitionedKeyGenerator"
COMPLEX_KEYGENERATOR_CLASS_OPT_VAL="org.apache.hudi.ComplexKeyGenerator"
PARTITIONPATH_FIELD_OPT_KEY="hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field"

#Incremental Constants
VIEW_TYPE_OPT_KEY="hoodie.datasource.query.type"
BEGIN_INSTANTTIME_OPT_KEY="hoodie.datasource.read.begin.instanttime"
VIEW_TYPE_INCREMENTAL_OPT_VAL="incremental"
END_INSTANTTIME_OPT_KEY="hoodie.datasource.read.end.instanttime"

df1 = sqlContext.read.parquet("PATH")
```

However, when we try to read the parquet file from s3 using spark sql we run into this error:

## error

```
"An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o90.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (ip-10-240-84-185.us-west-2.compute.internal executor 1): org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Parquet type not supported: INT32 (UINT_32)"
```

Does anyone see what the issue might be?
Is there any settings in DMS we need to change in order to export in a format pyspark can consume?
Is there a way to output parquet files from DMS in format supported by pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem in AWS DMS which exports the unsigned integer types which as they are without any mapping/transformation to another types supported by parquet.

You have multiple options to solve the problem:

1. Add transformation rules to your DMS migration job: chose json editor and add these rules

```json
{
"rules": [
   {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "1",
        "rule-name": "uint32-to-int32",
        "rule-action": "change-data-type",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "my_schema",
            "table-name": "%",
            "column-name": "%",
            "data-type": "uint4"
        },
        "data-type": {
            "type": "int4"
        }
   },
   {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "2",
        "rule-name": "unit64-to-int64",
        "rule-action": "change-data-type",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "my_schema",
            "table-name": "%",
            "column-name": "%",
            "data-type": "uint8"
        },
        "data-type": {
            "type": "int8"
        }
   }
]}
```

(you can add other rules based on your columns dtypes)

2. create a method in spark which read the schema from Glue metastore, transform all the unsigned types to supported ones, then read the parquets providing the transformed schema:

```py
df = spark.table(...)
custom_schema = transform_schema(df.schema) // develop this method which recursively check all the colums and create a new schema 
df = spark.read.schema(custom_schema).parquet("test.parquet")
```